# How can I correctly handle the deploy of some WSO2 ESB REST API in 2 differents environments? (containing, at the moment, hardcoded HATEOAS link)

Tags: jakarta-ee, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am not so into **WSO2 ESB** and I have the following situation that have to be handle. I try to explain it in details.

I have an **ESB** project containing some **REST APIs**. These REST APIs implements the **HATEOAS** concept. In practice I am simply adding the link to the returned resoruces. I am doing it using a script mediator that manipulated the JESON before return it, in my APIs I have something like this:

```
<script language="js">
<![CDATA[
    var log = mc.getServiceLog();
    function checkForNull(value) {
        if (value instanceof Object && "@nil" in value) {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    }

    log.info("----------- COMMODITY DETAILS JS SCRIPT START --------------------");
    // Strange workaround for getting JSON Payload. getPayloadJSON returned null. 
    var pl_string = mc.getProperty("JSONPayload"); 
    var payload = JSON.parse(pl_string);
    log.info("PAYLOAD STRING: " + pl_string);

    // Create new response:          
    var response = payload.Commodity.Commodity;
    log.info("RESPONSE: " + JSON.stringify(response));

    // Convert array of markets into required HATEOS format
    var markets = new Array();

    // Convert array of markets into required HATEOS format:
    for (i = 0; i < response.markets.el.length; ++i) {
        log.info("MARKET " + i);
        var el = response.markets.el[i];

        var newEl = new Object();

        newEl.market_id = el.market_id;
        newEl.market_name = el.market_name;

        // Convert null values:
        newEl.region = checkForNull(el.region);
        newEl.province = checkForNull(el.province);
        newEl.city = checkForNull(el.city);
        newEl.district = checkForNull(el.district);
        newEl.town = checkForNull(el.town);
        newEl.village = checkForNull(el.village);


        newEl.rel = "market_details";
        newEl.href = "http://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.KKK:8280/market_details/" + el.market_id;
        newEl.type = "GET";

        markets.push(newEl);
    }

    response.markets = markets;

    log.info("RESPONSE AFTER checkForNull(): " + JSON.stringify(response));

    // Put payload back:
    mc.setPayloadJSON(response);
    log.info("----------- COMMODITY DETAILS JS SCRIPT END --------------------");
]]>
</script>
```

As you can see in this script mediator I am adding the **HATEOAS** link:

```
    newEl.rel = "market_details";
    newEl.href = "http://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.KKK:8280/market_details/" + el.market_id;
    newEl.type = "GET";
```

I don't know if it is the neater solution but it is working fine and at the moment I can't chage it.

The problem is that I am hardcoding the href **URL** into the previous JavaScript that manipulate my JSON.

Now I have 2 environments: one for DEV and another one for PROD. And I have a lot of APIs. I know that I can simply do a string search and replace (I search for the **XXX.YYY.ZZZ.KKK** DEV URL replacing it with the PROD URL before deploy in PROD).

But I think that this is an absolutly dirty and horrible solution.

So: what could be neater solution?

My idea is:

- I create a new sequence that contains a **current_env** property in which I set the URL of the environment.
- I include this sequence at the beginning of every **ESB** file containing the definition of my API.
- I retrieve the value of this property into my **script** mediator and I use it to generate my **HATEOAS** link.

Could be this a pretty decent solution? Or exist some better way to do it? (maybe a value like this can be stored somewhere else different from a sequence? I really don't know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning URL's in script mediator or in the code is a bad practice,Rather than following this approach you can add the URL in Local Entries, fetch the value in your sequence and then append in script mediator, so in this case whenever a CAR file is deployed that will have generic code and all dynamic artifacts can be mentioned in local entires.

Comment: Ok man, I am stufying this local entry concept and it seems that is what I need. So the idea is to simply put this information into a local entry? When I have to change the environment I will simply change the local entry value? Is it?

Comment: Yes, Whenever you are shipping the code from DEV to PROD, you ship in CAR file, so CAR file will have your generic and tested code, Now if you keep dynamic changes in local entry then you can easily modify those things without touching the tested code.